# Photoshop: Filter>Render>Flame is not availabe

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I am a beginner in Photoshop and trying to add flame in my image but I couldn't find that option at `Filter>Render>Flame`. I am using Photoshop CC 2015 version. Anybody please tell me how can I get that option?

[image]

Note: **Photoshop has been updated to CC2017** and the filter is still missing.

Comment: What do you mean by it? Please explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your Photoshop! Because you are already using CC you can update using the Creative Cloud app.

Edit: Did some research and my previous statement may be untrue. You may have your 3D settings wrong or your computer doesn't have enough RAM to use the 3D settings. Check that you have "Use Graphics Processor" checked.

Comment: I checked it. I am using Graphics processor. May you can right about 3D settings how can I improve them?

Comment: My apologies! Are you on a Mac or a PC? You need at least 512mb of VRAM. If you are on a Mac with El Capitan check this way: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7516331?start=0&tstart=0 - If you are on a PC check this way: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001307.htm

Comment: I am using PC and I have Total Available Graphics Memory : 1664 MB and Dedicated Video Memory : 32 MB

Comment: That is your problem, you need at least 512mb of Video Memory. 32mb is not enough for it to use the 3D capabilities. https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/system-requirements.html

Comment: So, In my case how can I increase my Video Memory?

Comment: @NabiaSaroosh to "increase video memory" you need a **video card** with more memory. It's a **hardware issue** not merely a setting somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the latest version of Photoshop CC, make sure you create a path to use this feature otherwise the option will be inactive in the menu. I found this helpful:

> You need to create your path first (using the pen tool or any of the
>   shape tools), then choose  Filter > Render > Flames. (Note: you need
>   to have a pixel layer targeted in the Layers panel as a landing place
>   for the flame to be created, not a Shape, Type, or Smart Object layer.
>   You can however convert type to paths or use the Type Mask tool to
>   render paths for letter forms).
>
> As you can see from the dialog below, there are a large number of
>   options that can be customized in a number of ways. The six different
>   Flame Types are:
>
> • One Flame Along Path: A single flame will be rendered on each path.
>
> • Multiple Flames Along Path: More than one flame will be rendered on
>   each path. The flames will follow the direction of the path.
>
> • Multiple Flames One Direction: Multiple Flames will be rendered on
>   each path. All of the flames will point in the same direction.
>
> • Multiple Flames Path Directed: Multiple Flames will be rendered on
>   each path. Each Flame will point according to the path angle.
>
> • Multiple Flames Various Angle: Multiple Flames will be rendered on a
>   path. Each Flame will point randomly. You can control the angle
>   variation by changing the “angle” parameter.
>
> • Candle Light: One candle light will be rendered on a path.
>
> **Source:** *[Flame Generation comes to Photoshop CC!](http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2014/10/flame-generation-comes-to-photoshop-cc.html)*